# Python: using float from previous iteration of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Sorry if this question has already been answered elsewhere but I'm not sure of the specific terminology to find it.

What I want to do with this code is:

1. Add min(groundtempall) to an empty list
2. Add c+groundtempCtext[i-1] to groundtempCtext for every iteration of the for loop so that groundtempCtext[i-1] is the float that was added in the PREVIOUS iteration or in the case of the first iteration it is min(groundtempall).

When I try to run this I am getting the error.
Runtime error (IndexOutOfRangeException): index out of range: 1

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this/tell me where I am going wrong Thankyou!

```
groundtempCtext = []

groundtempCtext.append(min(groundtempall))

for i in range(1,len(divisionPts1)):
    c = (max(groundtempall)-min(groundtempall))/(len(divisionPts1)-1)
    groundtempCtext.append(c+groundtempCtext[i-1])

groundtempCtext.append(max(groundtempall))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just keep track of the total, you could use a list comp but a loop will be easier to understand:

```
c = (max(ground_temp_all) - min(ground_temp_all)) / (len(division_pts1)-1) # calculate once as it does not change
ground_temp_c_text = [min(ground_temp_all)] # just add min directly to list.
tot = ground_temp_c_text[0]  # set total to  first value in the list
for _ in range(1, len(division_pts1)):
    tot += c # same as adding c to the last value in the list
    ground_temp_c_text.append(tot)
```

I also changed your variable to use underscores which is the pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension instead of the loop.

```
stepSize = (max(groundtempall)-min(groundtempall))/(len(divisionPts1)-1)
groundtempCtext = [min(groundtempall) + ind * stepSize for ind in range(len(divisionPts1))]
```